# Is it more reliable to rely on index of occurrence or keywords when parsing websites?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

Just started using XPath, I'm parsing a website with lxml.

Is it preferable to do:

```
number_I_want = parsed_body.xpath('.//b')[6].text 
#or
number_I_want = parsed_body.xpath('.//span[@class="class_name"]')[0].text
```

I'd rather find this out now, rather than much further down the line. Actually I couldn't get something like the second expression to work for my particular case.

But essentially, the question: is it better to rely on `class` names (or other keywords) or indices of occurrence (such as 7th occurrence of bolded text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that it is generally better to rely on `id` attributes, or `class` by default, than on the number and order of appearance of specific tags.
That is more resilient to change in the page content.